# RIDE - some Library/Resource are RED

Tags: python, robotframework

Some Library/Resource in my Robot Framework script are RED as shown below:
 [bad script with red marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgpoz.jpg)

While other one (which I copied from) is looks OK:
 [good script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hShqb.jpg)

My working environment (tree) looks like this:
 [working environment/tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imyeU.jpg)

What I don't understand is why in one script everything looks good and in the other one (which looks almost the same) some Library/Resource are RED.

The main reason I ask is because my python script (stability_tests.py) is not getting the parameters I send (stability_args, see below).

[my robot framework script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFXkf.jpg)

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags        Critical    template    Conf=3    isTor=0    isSanity=0    

headless    rcmd
Library           BeAm.beacon.tests.BeaconTesting    WITH NAME    
BeaconTesting
Library           Collections
Library           BeAm.beacon.stability_tests
Library           BeAm.beacon.tests
Resource          ../../BeAm/beacon/settings.txt
Resource          ../../BeAm/settings.txt
Resource          ../../BeAm/local_settings.txt

*** Test Cases ***
Create Test Object
    [Tags]    must
    ${TEST} =    BeaconTesting.Get Beacon Test    3
    Set Suite Variable    ${TEST}    ${TEST}

Prepare Beacon Server
    [Tags]    prpr
    BeaconTesting.Change Mss Value    ${None}
    BeaconTesting.Prepare Server    ${TEST}

Beacon Stability
    [Tags]    stability
    ${stability_args} =    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${stability_args}    RANDOM_BEACON_TYPES    False
    Set To Dictionary    ${stability_args}    TIME_GAP    0.3
    Set To Dictionary    ${stability_args}    STRESS_TEST_NUM_OF_REQ    20
    Set To Dictionary    ${stability_args}    WORKERS    2
    stability workers    ${TEST}    &{stability_args}
```

BTW, the python script include stability_workers function.

```
def stability_workers(RANDOM_BEACON_TYPES=True, TIME_GAP=60, STRESS_TEST_NUM_OF_REQ=100000, WORKERS=25):
    s = NewStressTest(RANDOM_BEACON_TYPES, float(TIME_GAP), int(WORKERS), int(STRESS_TEST_NUM_OF_REQ)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below approach

1)Give absolute path in environment variable till **BeAm.beacon**

2) If 1 is not successfull,Create a environment variable PYTHONPATH and provide the absolute path till **BeAm.beacon**

This should solve your issue

Comment: An up vote and closing the answer will certainly help..Thnks

Comment: Thank you Pankaj.
One thing I forgot to mention is that I use PyCharm to investigate/develop, and for some reason when I don't use PyCharm the issues I mention above doesn't happen, meaning I do get "stability_args" from Robot Framework script into my Python script.

Comment: I can't comment on this  as I never used pycharm

Comment: You can also add paths to PYTHONPATH from RIDE>Tools>Preferences.